# How do I 'garbage collect' when I need to notify the other objects that one died?

Tags: python, reference, garbage-collection

I'm working on [a language that compiles to Brainfuck](https://github.com/Pseudonymous-Programmer/lang-A--), and I need help being able to update the objects when one of their fellows is 'garbage collected' (wiping its memory and shunting the other memory that many slots left) so that they refer to the correct position in memory. However, the problem with keeping a list of objects to update them is that Python's garbage collector can't do the hard work for me now since they still have one reference alive in our list of objects even if the one that's being used is deleted.

TLDR: See example code.

```
class Array_Claim:
    def __init__(self,array,index,del_enabled = False):
        self.index = index
        self.array = array
        self.del_enabled = del_enabled
    def value(self):
        return self.array.get(self.index)
    def delete(self):
        self.array.delete(self.index)
    def __del__(self):
        if(self.del_enabled):
            print("Del method called!")
            self.delete()

class Array:
    def __init__(self):
        self._array = []
        self._claims = [] #we need to update the other claim's indexes after one is deleted
    def new(self,value,del_enabled = False):
        self._array.append(value)
        result = Array_Claim(self,len(self._array)-1,del_enabled)
        self._claims.append(result)
        return result
    def delete(self,index):
        self._array.pop(index)
        self._claims.pop(index)
        for i in range(index,len(self._claims)):
            self._claims[i].index = i 
    def add(self,claim1,claim2):
        return self.new(self._array[claim1.index] + self._array[claim2.index])

#works fine when del isn't enabled.
print("Test one")
array = Array()
var = array.new(5)
var.delete()
print(array._array)

#However,we have problems collecting anonymous objects now
print("Test 2")
array = Array()
var = array.add(array.new(2),array.new(3))
var.delete()
print(array._array)

#Let's try enabling our del method!
print("Test 3")
#works
array = Array()
var = array.new(5,True)
var.delete()
print(array._array)

#crashes and burns because it was deleted twice somehow...
print("Test 4")
array = Array()
var = array.new(5,True)
del var
print(array._array)

#Our anonymous objects that we did this for don't even collect theirselves!
print("Test 5")
array = Array()
array.add(array.new(2),array.new(3))
print(array._array)
```

Comment: "However, the problem with keeping a list of objects to update them is that Python's garbage collector can't do the hard work for me now since they still have one reference alive in our list of objects even if the one that's being used is deleted." - weak references could solve that, but I don't know how you'd be using Python's GC or even anything Python at all at runtime if you're going to transpile to Brainfuck.

Comment: Memory is allocated by using a 'claim' object (in Python), which represents a chunk of Brainfuck memory. As the 'claim' objects are garbage collected in Python, either by being anonymous or being explicitly deleted by the user, I thought it would be a good idea to clear the memory and transport everything to its right that many slots left to save in `>`s and `<`s in our Brainfuck code. Thanks for telling me about `weakref`, though, that was **exactly** what I wanted!